# Ubuntu server desktop environment, minimal install

Tags: server, gui

Brand new to Linux less than a week ago and have to set up a small remote company file server. Went from full ver dsktop env GUI which worked fine from boot to dsktop env GUI in minimal config after fresh reinstall Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Can't figure out how to start GUI now after 3 hours of searching.  Screen stops at

```
[ok] Reached target Graphical Interface.
[ok] Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.    
     Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[ok] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
     Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
[ok] Stopped target Graphical Interface.
[ok] Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[ok]  Started X.org diagnosis failsafe.
[ok]  Reached target Graphical failsafe fallback.
[ok]  Started Daily apt download activities.
```

I can get to terminal from this point with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but can't toggle into GUI. Just wanted the GUI to set up the storage drive before setting up Samba.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A "minimal" install of server software, doesn't include a GUI. You have to install and configure a desktop environment. Minimal installation gives you what's called a "head-less" setup. Everything is configured via the command line, or you SSH into the box and configure.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I did a headless install then wanted to add a GUI so I installed the complete Desktop Environment GUI which worked fine from boot then I reinstalled Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS and did a minimal install for Desktop Environment to limit the overhead and I can't get the GUI working.  I can get to the command line but I want to get the GUI working in minimal configuration.

Comment: Easiest thing I would do, if you have another system to SSH into it from, is something like X2Go. It's remote desktop. Still headless on the server side, but you can have gui on your system.